# When changing the encoding setting in IE, the jsp page get the error Webpage has expired

Tags: browser

I write a jsp page and run it in jboss. When I change the encoding setting in IE, the page get the error Webpage has expired.

I want to know how to avoid this problem in IE. In firefox, there is no such kind of problem.